# How do i display the count of checkboxes ticked on an html page?

Tags: html, jquery

I want to display the number of checkboxes ticked in the span element.
How do i achieve this?
This is my code -

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var n =$("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
$("span").text(n);

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox">Red
<input type="checkbox">Green
<div id="result">
<p><span>0</span> are checked </p></div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: change your code to this `$("input:checkbox").change(function () {
                $("span").text($("[type='checkbox']:checked").length);});`

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener on each, and updated the number of checked inputs on `change`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $.each($("[type='checkbox']"), inp => {
          $(this).on('change', getChecked)
     });
     function getChecked(){
          var n = $("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
          $("span").text(n);
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox">Red
<input type="checkbox">Green
<div id="result">
<p><span>0</span> are checked </p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add change function to checkbox type.
The correct code is this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
      var n =$("[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
      $('span').text(n); 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox">Red
<input type="checkbox">Green
<div id="result">
<p><span>0</span> are checked </p></div>
```